How to fix android blur does not looks like iOS blur (expo-blur)
Im using expo react natve to build my app,
ViewBlur to use blur on camera page when user need to see loading so he will see the camera blur(change orientation etc.)
the problem is in iOS its looks very good but in android its looks lame (not like a blur more like a backgroundcolor white view with opacity...)
iOS blur:

Android blur:

this is the code:
{isBlur && (
                    <BlurView
                      tint="regular"
                      intensity={100}
                      experimentalBlurMethod="dimezisBlurView"
                      style={{
                        zIndex: 2,
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        position: 'absolute',
                      }}
                    />
                  )}

Try anything in expo document/every props and still does not help

A simple fix will be to update your expo sdk version to 50+

Already 50... still same problem
